# Blobs don't always appear, - refresh issue

Tags: php, blob

Blob sometimes shows...

I have a small gallery using blobs, however sometimes the image shows; and sometimes they don't... (Just keep refreshing and you'll know what I mean)

http://courtlandshouse.co.uk/test.php

Code for displaying the blobs...

```
include('../connect.php');

$imS = "SELECT id, cv, gv, ".$_REQUEST['blob']." AS img FROM $tbb WHERE pal = '1' AND id = 
'".$_REQUEST['id']."' LIMIT 1";
$imQ = mysql_query($imS);
$imD = mysql_fetch_object($imQ);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $imD->img;
exit;
```

Not sure what the issue is since they download sometimes, but not all the time.

Comment: And when it is a wrong case, what is happening?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer your question, but your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Please give us also the insert statement and the table structure.

Comment: Table Structure: Too long to copy and paste, however the field is a simple blob field.

Comment: I have made it secure :)

Comment: And the insert - maybe there is some binary to text conversion...